# Adding input tags dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I am taking the amount from one input box and creating a `for...each` loop to add input boxes. But I have run into a problem. I tried using `append()` and `html()` - `append()` keeps adding more boxes than needed and `html()` only adds the last one. Which are both correct. But I need the input boxes to be exactly what the amount is. And if the input box changes again, I need it to re update.

here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/liveandream/mRY3d/

I hope this makes sense... and hopefully someone can help me!! Thanks in advance..

Comment: I entered 4 in your jsFiddle and saw 2 sets of inputs show up.  Isn't that what should show up?  I'm not sure I understand what your problem is then.

Comment: If you change the number of children, it's appending a whole new set of boxes instead of replacing the old ones.

Comment: Please have a look at my solution and see if it fits your needs better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add:

```
$('.extrakids').empty();
```

Right before your `for` loop;

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/mRY3d/22/

My answer solves a lot of issues.

If you add or remove children you don't overwrite boxes and lose any data put in those boxes.

The update is timed out so if a user slips the JS loop won't crash if it tries to make too many. I maxed out the children created as well.

I left the html where it belonged and created the inputs from it.

And I fixed the original issue.